# Erro: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou a fazer um trabalho em html, css, javascript e ajax e  o objetivo é mudar o estilo da tab com o id do nome do sensor quando é clicada, mas diz que o elemento não existe e queria saber qual o erro que estou a cometer.

Basicamente estou a importar de um ficheiro xml e a colocar as tabs com o id do nome do sensor do ficheiro xml dentro de uma tag com o nome list_sensores

```
        strHtmlNomes = "";
        for(i = 0; i < nomesSensores.length; i++)
        {
            nomeSensor = nomesSensores[i];
            strHtmlNomes +='<div><a href="#" id="'+nomeSensor+'" class="tablinks" onclick="openSensor('+nomeSensor+')">'+nomeSensor+'</a></div>';       
        }



        document.getElementById("list_sensores").innerHTML = strHtmlNomes;
```

e antes de fechar o html tenho este script javascript

```
function openSensor(nomeSensor){
    document.getElementById(nomeSensor).style.color = "blue";
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu ID for numérico, adicione também alguma letra.

Altere a atribuição da variável `nomeSensor` para:

```
nomeSensor = "sensor_" + nomesSensores[i];
```

---

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987636/why-cant-i-have-a-numeric-value-as-the-id-of-an-element

Comment: a variável  nomeSensor  nunca é numérica

Comment: O nome se repete em alguns casos, ou são apenas nomes únicos? São usados espaços no nome atribuido ao id?

Comment: o nome é sempre unico 

<sensor id="1">
<nome>Temperatura</nome>
<descricao>Sensor de temperatura</descricao>
</sensor>
<sensor id="2">
<nome>Qualidade_do_ar</nome>
<descricao>Sensor de qualidade do ar</descricao>
</sensor>
<sensor id="3">
<nome>Fluxo_de_transito</nome>
<descricao>Sensor de fluxo de transito</descricao>
</sensor>
<sensor id="4">
<nome>Atividade_cardiaca</nome>
<descricao>Sensor de atividade cardiaca instalado em pessoas</descricao>
</sensor>

Comment: o id do html está com o nome do sensor não com o número, a lista de sensores é o ficheiro xml

Comment: Talvez seja o seu parâmetro `onclick`, como você está passando uma string como argumento para sua função, tente colocar no HTML assim:
`onclick="openSensor(\'' + nomeSensor + '\')">'`